# Is this the right way to call addtional route in Laravel 8 from view?

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel and learning mostly by laravel docs and other resources online. This is my first post on asking for help on forums, so please bear with me. I am having an issue in calling a route from laravel blade.

In my view blade I have dropdown selection for list of businesses which user can select from. When user select the business it will call route the route below.

This is my route that I am trying to call from my view.

```
Route::group(['as' => 'frontend.', 'namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'subscribed']], function () {
        
   Route::get('/businesses/{business_id}', 'BusinessesController@business')->name('business');
});
```

In my view frontend header blade I am listing all the business user has access to

```
@if (auth()->user()->businesses->count() > 1)
   <div class="d-flex align-items-center" data-select2-id="select2-data-14-ocz7">
      <select class="form-control" name="business_id" id="business_id" onchange="showBusinessData(this.value)">
          <?php $businesses = auth()->user()->businesses; ?>
             @foreach($businesses as $business)
                <option value="{{$business->id}} {{ session('business_id', '') }}" <?php if(session('business_id') == $business->id) echo "selected"; ?>>{{ $business->business_name }} <a href="{{ route('frontend.business', $business->id) }}"></a></option>
             @endforeach
       </select>
     </div>
  @endif
```

Above view does not load the route.

Comment: "It's not working"... Have you some errors? Is the business defined by business_id is loaded (var_dump in controller) ?

Comment: You have to be exact with the terms in both your title and question so that one can get a true picture of the problem. What you have here is not a Resource Controller. The only resource I see here is *user*. Do you have a *business* class? Use the php artisan command on the command line to create resource controller: `php artisan make:controller BusinessController --resource`

Comment: @UdoE. Thank you for clarification. I have BusinessController where I have the CRUD functions and Business Model as well. Business() function mentioned above is the additional function in the BusinessController which I am trying to call from my view. All the business are loaded in the view and when I select one from dropdown it does not call the function Business in Business controller. I am not getting any error so not sure what to do next. I wanted to see if the route called from view on selection is correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. In my view blade I have set for onchange to call function in js. I just had to update to set the window href location to the route.

```
function showBusinessData(val){
   window.location.href = val;
}
```